# Using extension in Opencart

Tags: php, module, opencart

I am just newbie to [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/). I have purchased an extension. The link is [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6091). Now I want to know where to place this extension in my [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) folder.I don't know how to use extension in [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/). So can someone tell me where to place the extension and how to active the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step tutorial on installing OpenCart Extensions. (opencart add-ons) Developed on vQmod
The article will take you through
1)  How to install vQmod
2)  Installing OpenCart extensions through FTP
3)  Common problems  and errors faced  during installations

www.transpacific-software.com/guide_install_opencart_extensions.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no unified way to install an extension, it can be a plain module or can use vQmod or some other approach.

However, in most cases directory structure of the extension corresponds with directory structure of openCart itself. If it has same folders, like **catalog/** or **admin/**, you just upload them on top of the openCart folders (but back up your current files first).

But if unsure, the best way would be to look for installation instructions, and if there are none, contact the developer.

The extension you mentioned has this under Documentation tab:

> Just need to find the text and replace with my code.

Without knowing the content of the extension, it's hard to say what exactly does it mean though.

As for activation, if the extension is a module, you go to *Extensions - Modules* in admin, find your extension there and click **Install**. In many cases, no activation is needed, it'll be active as soon as you upload the files. In other cases it may have its' own installation / activation script.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your admin panel, In the 'Extension' menu, click on the 'Extension Installer',  then upload your file.. after completion, under the Extension menu , click on Modifications'. and on the top right there is an option for refresh changes and install the module if it doesn't installed automatically..